# Finding largest prime factor from inputted number

Tags: c#, beginner, primes, console

This is my first C# console application. This program asks for an input of a number, and finds the highest prime factor of that number. Please review my code.

- Have I used things right?
- Is my code efficient?
- Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Problems
{
    class Program
    {
        static int FindFactor(Int64 UserInput)
        {
            int LargestFactor = 0;
            Int64 Number = UserInput;

            for (int i = 2; i < Number; i++)
            {
                if (Number % i == 0)
                { 
                    if (PrimeFactorCheck(i) == true)
                    {
                        LargestFactor = i;
                    }
                }
            }
            return LargestFactor;
        }
        static bool PrimeFactorCheck(int Number)
        {
            bool PrimeNumberValidity = true;

            for(int i = 2; i < Number; i++)
            {
                if (PrimeNumberValidity == true)
                {
                    if (Number % i == 0)
                    {
                        PrimeNumberValidity = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    i = Number;
                }
            }

            return PrimeNumberValidity;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Hello, please enter a number to find the biggest prime factor of it: ");
             Int64 UserInput = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());

            int Answer = FindFactor(UserInput);
            Console.WriteLine(Answer);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Problems
{
```

You can make this class static since it doesn't make sense to make instances of it.

```
    static class Program
    {
```

Local variables are usually not capitalized.

```
        static int FindFactor(Int64 userInput)
        {
```

The compiler can infer the type if you use `var`, so you won't have to repeat it.

```
            var largestFactor = 0L;
            var number = userInput;

            for (var i = 2; i < number; ++i)
            {
```

Use `&&` instead of nested if-statements.

```
                if (number % i == 0 && IsPrimeFactor(i))
                {
                    largestFactor = i;
                }
            }

            return largestFactor;
        }
```

Usually you put a blank line between function definitions.

Functions returning Booleans are often called "IsBlaBla" instead of "BlaBlaCheck."

```
        static bool IsPrimeFactor(int number)
        {
            var primeNumberValidity = true;

            for(int i = 2; i < number; ++i)
            {
                if (primeNumberValidity && number % i == 0)
                {
                    primeNumberValidity = false;
```

You can exit the loop here because continuing is useless.

```
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = number;
                }
            }

            return primeNumberValidity;
        }
```

`args` is not used, so you can omit it.

```
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Hello, please enter a number to find the biggest prime factor of it: ");

            var userInput = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());

            var answer = FindFactor(userInput);
            Console.WriteLine(answer);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can use LINQ to implement `FindFactor` in a functional fashion, rather than imperatively.

```
static int FindFactor(Int64 number) {
    return IEnumerable.Range(2, number - 2)
                      .Where(n => number % n == 0 && IsPrimeFactor(n))
                      .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                      .Last();
}
```

Comment: `var largestFactor = 0;` gives you an `Int64`?

Comment: Oh use `0L` then.

Answer (score 8):

Your algorithm is not only inefficient, it is also incorrect.  Let's assume that assume that the `PrimeFactorCheck()` function works correctly, and just focus on this function:

```
static int FindFactor(Int64 UserInput)
{
    int LargestFactor = 0;
    Int64 Number = UserInput;

    for (int i = 2; i < Number; i++)
    {
        if (Number % i == 0)
        { 
            if (PrimeFactorCheck(i) == true)
            {
                LargestFactor = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return LargestFactor;
}
```

First, a nitpick: the renaming of `UserInput` to `Number` is pointless.  You might as well have named the function parameter properly in the first place.

The function is incorrect, in that it will return 0 if the input is prime.  Rather, I would expect it to return the input itself if it is prime.

If the input is an `Int64`, you should also prepare for the possibility that its largest prime factor also occupies up to 64 bits.  <s>You should prefer integral types `long` or `ulong` over the `System.Int64` structure.</s>

One suggestion would be to iterate backwards — `for (int i = Number; i > 0; i--)` — and return as soon as you find a factor that is prime.  That would be a significant optimization, but it still leaves lots of room for improvement.

The for-loop iterations could be reduced by over 75%.  You only need to test factors <s>up to `Number / 2`</s> up to an including \$\sqrt{\textrm{Number}}\$, eliminating <s>half</s> most of the loop.  Furthermore, since 2 is the only even prime, you can skip all subsequent even candidates, eliminating another half.

A much better strategy would be to reduce `Number` every time you encounter a factor.  Not only is it sometimes possible to *vastly* reduce the size of the `Number` very quickly, you can also avoid `PrimeFactorCheck()` altogether — and you don't need to be a cryptographer to know that checking whether a large number is prime is computationally intensive.

```
static Int64 FindLargestFactor(Int64 n)
{
    if (n == 2) return 2;
    while (n % 2 == 0) n = n / 2;
    for (Int64 i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        while (n % i == 0) n = n / i;
    }
    return n;
}
```

For comparison, my `FindLargestFactor(360)` only needs to perform 6 modulo-division operations, for a total of 12.  Your original `FindFactor(360)` and its `PrimeFactorCheck()`s would take 384 modulo operations altogether.

Comment: Saying "you should prefer `long` to `Int64`" is nonsensical -- they are two different names for the same type.  Do not encourage people to use `ulong` unless they are writing C interop code. Suggest `BigInteger` if you need an integer bigger than a long.

Comment: You only need to check factors up to the square root of n, not up to n/2!

Comment: @Théophile you need to be careful with that. You only need to check up to sqrt(n) in order to check whether n is prime, but that's because if there is a factor greater than sqrt(n), there will also be a corresponding factor less than sqrt(n). There are still factors greater than sqrt(n), so when you're searching for the largest it could be anything up to n/2. For example, `19 * 2 = 38` and `19 > sqrt(38)`. You could still stop at sqrt(n), but only if you check the corresponding factor greater than sqrt(n) each time you find one less than sqrt(n). Either, neither or both could be prime.

Comment: @Théophile P.S welcome to Code Review!

Comment: @githubphagocyte Yes, when you find a prime `p` you should of course factor it out and resume the search on `n/p` and start the iteration at `p` because there are no smaller prime factors. There are much better algorithms out there, but this will do the trick for small `n`. (P.S. Thank you! :))

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio likes to add a bunch of `using` statements when you create a new console program. You can get rid of these. You're not using Linq or multithreading.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```