# Retrieves Data From Various Excel Sheets Online, sorts, edits, and Analyzes said Data

Tags: performance, beginner, vba, excel

This is a routine I wrote to streamline analysis I need to do that originally took 1.5 hours and now takes about 4 minutes total run time.

I'm fairly new to Excel VBA so I welcome all criticism and advice!

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr _
      ) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
      Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
        ByVal lpszUrlName As String _
      ) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
      ) As Long
    Private Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
      Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
        ByVal lpszUrlName As String _
      ) As Long
#End If

Public Const ERROR_SUCCESS As Long = 0
Public Const BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION As Long = &H10
Public Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD As Long = &H80000000
Public Const csURL As String = "http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductDetailsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate=×d×&reportType=P&productId=×p×"

Sub Pull_CME_Data()

Dim getBook As String, OiProductCodesArray() As String
Dim cmeDataBook As Workbook
Dim data As Worksheet, controlPanel As Worksheet, lo As Worksheet, wa As Worksheet, sevenA As Worksheet, oh As Worksheet, at As Worksheet, ob As Worksheet, ra As Worksheet, cvr As Worksheet, ln As Worksheet, wtioi As Worksheet, rboboi As Worksheet, ethanoloi As Worksheet, heatoi As Worksheet, sevenaoi As Worksheet, waoi As Worksheet, ngoi As Worksheet, atoi As Worksheet, raoi As Worksheet, volumeSheet As Worksheet
Dim ClearWshtsArray As Variant, OiWshtsArray As Variant
Dim WshtNameCrnt As Variant, OiWshtsCrnt As Variant
Dim oiProductCodesArrayCounter As Integer

'Initial declarations and setup
    getBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set cmeDataBook = Workbooks(getBook)
    Set data = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Data")
    Set controlPanel = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Control Panel")
    Set lo = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Lo")
    Set wa = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Wa")
    Set sevenA = cmeDataBook.Sheets("7A")
    Set oh = cmeDataBook.Sheets("oh")
    Set at = cmeDataBook.Sheets("at")
    Set ob = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Ob")
    Set ra = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Ra")
    Set cvr = cmeDataBook.Sheets("CVR")
    Set ln = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Ln")
    Set wtioi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("WtiOI")
    Set rboboi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("RbobOI")
    Set ethanoloi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("EthanolOI")
    Set heatoi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("HeatOI")
    Set sevenaoi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("7AOI")
    Set waoi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("WAOI")
    Set ngoi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("NGOI")
    Set atoi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("ATOI")
    Set raoi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("RAOI")
    Set volumeSheet = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Total Volume By Product (CME)")


'Sets three arrays for iteration through different sheets
    ClearWshtsArray = Array(data.Name, lo.Name, wa.Name, sevenA.Name, oh.Name, at.Name, ob.Name, ra.Name, _
    cvr.Name, ln.Name, wtioi.Name, rboboi.Name, ethanoloi.Name, heatoi.Name, sevenaoi.Name, waoi.Name, _
    raoi.Name)

    OiWshtsArray = Array(wtioi.Name, rboboi.Name, ethanoloi.Name, heatoi.Name, sevenaoi.Name, waoi.Name, ngoi.Name, atoi.Name, raoi.Name)

    OiProductCodesArray() = Split(controlPanel.Cells(4, 13).Value2, "or")

    On Error GoTo bailOut

'Preparation for execution
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = True

'Clears data sheets of anything prior
    For Each WshtNameCrnt In ClearWshtsArray

        Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt).Activate

        With Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt)
            .UsedRange.Clear
        End With

    Next WshtNameCrnt

    Call GetTotalVolumeData(volumeSheet, controlPanel)

'For CSV data file
    controlPanel.Activate
    Cells(2, 1).Select
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="ftp://ftp.cmegroup.com/pub/settle/nymex_option.csv"
        Windows("nymex_option.csv").Visible = True

'Copies data and transfers to data tab
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy

    data.Activate
    With data
        .Cells(1, 1).Select
        .Paste
        .Cells(1, 1).Select
    End With

'Clears clipboard and closes CSV file to avoid potential contamination
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("nymex_option.csv").Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks("nymex_option.csv").Close

'Brings OI data by product
    For oiProductCodesArrayCounter = 0 To UBound(OiProductCodesArray)

        Call GetOiData(OiProductCodesArray(oiProductCodesArrayCounter), Sheets(OiWshtsArray(oiProductCodesArrayCounter)), controlPanel)

    Next oiProductCodesArrayCounter

'Gets Lo Data sorted and cleaned
    Call seperateData(cmeDataBook, data, lo, "lo", 1500)

'Get WA data, format and paste
    Call seperateData(cmeDataBook, data, wa, "wa", 100)

'Get 7A data, format and paste
    Call seperateData(cmeDataBook, data, sevenA, "7a", 100)

'Get OH data, format and paste
    Call seperateData(cmeDataBook, data, oh, "oh", 100)

'Get AT data, format and paste
    Call seperateData(cmeDataBook, data, at, "at", 5)

'Get OB data, format and paste
    Call seperateData(cmeDataBook, data, ob, "ob", 100)

'Get RA data, format and paste
    Call seperateData(cmeDataBook, data, ra, "ra", 5)

'Get Ethanol Data, format and paste
    Call seperateData(cmeDataBook, data, cvr, "cvr", 5)

'Get Ln Data, format and paste
    Call seperateData(cmeDataBook, data, ln, "ln", 1000)

'Excel standard function cleanup
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    data.Activate
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
    controlPanel.Activate
    MsgBox ("Data dump file successfully pulled and analyzed")
    Exit Sub

'Error handler for routine wide errors
bailOut:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    controlPanel.Activate
    MsgBox ("Data dump file has failed.  Please check hyperlink, sheet names, date, and try again.")

End Sub

Sub GetTotalVolumeData(volumeSheet As Worksheet, controlSheet As Worksheet)

Dim getBook As String, energy As String
Dim newDataBook As Workbook
Dim newDataSheet As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, dataBookLRow As Long
Dim ProductCodes() As String
Dim counter As Integer

'Sets string variables and array
energy = "Energy"
ProductCodes() = Split(controlSheet.Cells(2, 17).Value2, "or")

Workbooks.Open Filename:=controlSheet.Cells(2, 8)
getBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'Set workbook name
Set newDataBook = Workbooks(getBook)
Set newDataSheet = newDataBook.Sheets(1)

dataBookLRow = newDataSheet.Cells(newDataSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For counter = 0 To UBound(ProductCodes)

'Counter iterating over the array to capture all the products
Call ProcessVolumeData(volumeSheet, ProductCodes(counter), newDataBook, dataBookLRow, controlSheet)

Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
newDataBook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
Sub ProcessVolumeData(volumeSheet As Worksheet, product As String, newDataBook As Workbook, dataBookLRow As Long, controlSheet As Worksheet)

Dim lRow As Long

'Finds lRow of Volume Sheet
lRow = volumeSheet.Cells(volumeSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

newDataBook.Activate

'WTI American
With newDataBook.Sheets(1)
    Cells(5, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        Selection.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=" & "Energy"
        Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Trim(product)
    Range("A6:M" & dataBookLRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
End With

volumeSheet.Activate

With volumeSheet
    .Cells((lRow + 1), 2).Select
    .Paste
    .Cells((lRow + 1), 2).Select
    .Cells((lRow + 1), 1) = controlSheet.Cells(1, 5).Value
End With


End Sub

Private Function seperateData(cmeDataBook As Workbook, data As Worksheet, productSheet As Worksheet, product As String, minimumVal As Integer)
'Finds product code in data table, formats it, and pastes into the relevant sheet

Dim rownum As Integer
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim contract As String
Dim productOiSheet As Worksheet

    data.Activate
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & product
        Selection.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=">=" & minimumVal
    Cells(1, 1).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy

    productSheet.Activate
    With productSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Select
        .Paste
        .Cells(1, 1).Select
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("R2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    'Prevents unecessary formatting of empty cells
    If IsEmpty(Cells(2, 1)) = True Then
        GoTo Skip
    End If

    'finds last row and sets row number
    lRow = productSheet.Cells(productSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    rownum = 2

    'Pastes Product Symbol into second column header and deletes first column
    productSheet.Cells(1, 2) = productSheet.Cells(2, 1)

    'Builds product code
    For counter = rownum To lRow
        Select Case productSheet.Cells(counter, 2)

        Case 1
            productSheet.Cells(counter, 2) = "F" & Right(productSheet.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 2
            productSheet.Cells(counter, 2) = "G" & Right(productSheet.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 3
            productSheet.Cells(counter, 2) = "H" & Right(productSheet.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 4
            productSheet.Cells(counter, 2) = "J" & Right(productSheet.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 5
            productSheet.Cells(counter, 2) = "K" & Right(productSheet.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 6
            productSheet.Cells(counter, 2) = "M" & Right(productSheet.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 7
            productSheet.Cells(counter, 2) = "N" & Right(productSheet.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 8
            productSheet.Cells(counter, 2) = "Q" & Right(productSheet.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 9
            productSheet.Cells(counter, 2) = "U" & Right(productSheet.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 10
            productSheet.Cells(counter, 2) = "V" & Right(productSheet.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 11
            productSheet.Cells(counter, 2) = "X" & Right(productSheet.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 12
            productSheet.Cells(counter, 2) = "Z" & Right(productSheet.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        End Select
    Next

    'changes C and P to puts
    For counter = rownum To lRow
        Select Case productSheet.Cells(counter, 5)

        Case "P"
            productSheet.Cells(counter, 5) = "PUT"

        Case "C"
            productSheet.Cells(counter, 5) = "CALL"

        End Select
    Next

    'General formatting for each analyzed sheet
    Columns("C:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("E:L").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("H:J").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    productSheet.Cells(1, 8) = "OI"
    productSheet.Cells(1, 9) = "Chg In OI"

    Select Case Cells(1, 1)

        Case "LO"
            Set productOiSheet = cmeDataBook.Sheets("WtiOI")

        Case "WA"
            Set productOiSheet = cmeDataBook.Sheets("WAOI")

        Case "7A"
            Set productOiSheet = cmeDataBook.Sheets("7AOI")

        Case "OH"
            Set productOiSheet = cmeDataBook.Sheets("HeatOI")

        Case "AT"
            Set productOiSheet = cmeDataBook.Sheets("ATOI")

        Case "OB"
            Set productOiSheet = cmeDataBook.Sheets("RbobOI")

        Case "RA"
            Set productOiSheet = cmeDataBook.Sheets("RAOI")

        Case "CVR"
            Set productOiSheet = cmeDataBook.Sheets("EthanolOI")

        Case "LN"
            Set productOiSheet = cmeDataBook.Sheets("NGOI")

    End Select

    Range("C2:C" & lRow).NumberFormat = "###.00"

    Call AnalyzeOiData(lRow, productOiSheet, productSheet, rownum)

    Columns("A:i").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1:i1").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    With Selection
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With

    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6

    productSheet.Select
    Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 42
    Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 26.25
    Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 39.75

    'Skips formatting practices for products that did not fit the value minimum
Skip:
    'Do nothing skip formatting
End Function

Sub FormatData(dataT As Worksheet)

'Formats Data T
Dim rownum As Integer
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim counter As Integer

dataT.Activate

'finds last row and sets row number
lRow = dataT.Cells(dataT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
rownum = 2

For counter = rownum To lRow
        Select Case dataT.Cells(counter, 2)

        Case 1
            dataT.Cells(counter, 2) = "F" & Right(dataT.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 2
            dataT.Cells(counter, 2) = "G" & Right(dataT.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 3
            dataT.Cells(counter, 2) = "H" & Right(dataT.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 4
            dataT.Cells(counter, 2) = "J" & Right(dataT.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 5
            dataT.Cells(counter, 2) = "K" & Right(dataT.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 6
            dataT.Cells(counter, 2) = "M" & Right(dataT.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 7
            dataT.Cells(counter, 2) = "N" & Right(dataT.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 8
            dataT.Cells(counter, 2) = "Q" & Right(dataT.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 9
            dataT.Cells(counter, 2) = "U" & Right(dataT.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 10
            dataT.Cells(counter, 2) = "V" & Right(dataT.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 11
            dataT.Cells(counter, 2) = "X" & Right(dataT.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        Case 12
            dataT.Cells(counter, 2) = "Z" & Right(dataT.Cells(counter, 3), 2)

        End Select
    Next

'changes C and P to puts
For counter = rownum To lRow
    Select Case dataT.Cells(counter, 5)

    Case "P"
        dataT.Cells(counter, 5) = "PUT"

    Case "C"
        dataT.Cells(counter, 5) = "CALL"

    End Select
Next

'Formats strikes and basic formatting
dataT.Range("F2:F" & lRow).NumberFormat = "###.00"
dataT.Columns("H:O").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
dataT.Columns("T:T").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
dataT.Columns("C:D").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub

Sub GetOiData(productID As String, targetSheet As Worksheet, controlPanel As Worksheet)
'Function access OI data from the CME website and copies it into the book for all products
Dim filePath As String
Dim reportDate As String
Dim w As Long, ret As Long, sWAN As String, sLAN As String, sNAM As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    reportDate = Format(controlPanel.Cells(1, 5).Value, "yyyymmdd")

    'sets potential file name and environTMP
    sNAM = Format(controlPanel.Cells(1, 5).Value, "\C\M\E\_OIL\_yyyymmdd")
    sLAN = Environ("TMP") & Chr(92) & Format(controlPanel.Cells(1, 5).Value, "\C\M\E\_OIL\_yyyymmdd.xl\s")

    'Testing for error sLAN
    If CBool(Len(Dir(sLAN, vbNormal))) Then Kill sLAN

    sWAN = Replace(Replace(csURL, _
                            "×d×", Format(controlPanel.Cells(1, 5).Value, "yyyymmdd")), _
                            "×p×", productID)

    ret = URLDownloadToFile(0&, sWAN, sLAN, BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, 0&)

    If ret = ERROR_SUCCESS Then

        With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sLAN, ReadOnly:=True)
            .Worksheets(1).Name = sNAM
            .Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Select
            Selection.Copy

            targetSheet.Activate
            With targetSheet
                .Cells(1, 1).Select
                .Paste
            End With

            .Worksheets(sNAM).Activate
            .Close savechanges:=False
        End With

        Kill sLAN

    Else

        If CBool(Err.Number) Then
            MsgBox (Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description)
        Else
            MsgBox ("Unable to download the file")
        End If

        Err.Clear

    End If

End Sub

Sub AnalyzeOiData(lRow As Integer, oiDataSheet As Worksheet, productSheet As Worksheet, rownum As Integer)

Dim counter As Integer
Dim monthExp As String
Dim oiLocationFinder As Range
Dim strikeRan As Range
Dim optStrike As Long
Dim locStor As Integer
Dim strikeLoc As Range
Dim emptyCounter As Integer
Dim continue As Boolean

For counter = rownum To lRow
    continue = True

    'Returns formatted monthcode for finding the different months of expiry embedded in the OI data
    monthExp = GetMonthCode(productSheet.Cells(counter, 1), productSheet.Cells(counter, 2))

    'multiplies the strike by 100 in an attempt to match the format in the OI sheet
    If productSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "OH" Or productSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "AT" Or productSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "OB" Then
        optStrike = productSheet.Cells(counter, 3).Value * 10000

    ElseIf productSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "LN" Then
        optStrike = productSheet.Cells(counter, 3).Value * 1000

    Else
        optStrike = productSheet.Cells(counter, 3).Value * 100
    End If

    'Sets OI finder in order to access Row data
    Set oiLocationFinder = oiDataSheet.Columns(1).Find(monthExp)
    locStor = oiLocationFinder.Row
    oiDataSheet.Activate
    Cells(locStor, 1).Select

    emptyCounter = locStor

    Do
    DoEvents

        If Cells(emptyCounter, 1) = optStrike Then
            continue = False
           Set strikeLoc = Range("A" & emptyCounter)

        ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(emptyCounter, 1)) = True Then
            continue = False

        Else
            emptyCounter = emptyCounter + 1

        End If

    Loop Until continue = False

    If strikeLoc Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Skip
    End If

    locStor = strikeLoc.Row

    productSheet.Cells(counter, 8) = oiDataSheet.Cells(locStor, 9)
    productSheet.Cells(counter, 9) = oiDataSheet.Cells(locStor, 10)

Skip:
    If IsEmpty(productSheet.Cells(counter, 8)) = True And IsEmpty(productSheet.Cells(counter, 9)) = True Then

        productSheet.Cells(counter, 8) = "NA"
        productSheet.Cells(counter, 9) = "NA"
    End If

    Set oiLocationFinder = Nothing
Next

End Sub

Function GetMonthCode(exp As String, optionType As String) As String
'Formats month code so that it is readable and can be located in OI tables

Dim monthYear As String
Dim year As Integer

    year = Right(exp, 2)

    Select Case exp

        Case "F" & year
            monthYear = "JAN" & " " & Right(exp, 2) & " "

        Case "G" & year
            monthYear = "FEB" & " " & Right(exp, 2) & " "

        Case "H" & year
            monthYear = "MAR" & " " & Right(exp, 2) & " "

        Case "J" & year
            monthYear = "APR" & " " & Right(exp, 2) & " "

        Case "K" & year
            monthYear = "MAY" & " " & Right(exp, 2) & " "

        Case "M" & year
            monthYear = "JUN" & " " & Right(exp, 2) & " "

        Case "N" & year
            monthYear = "JUL" & " " & Right(exp, 2) & " "

        Case "Q" & year
            monthYear = "AUG" & " " & Right(exp, 2) & " "

        Case "U" & year
            monthYear = "SEP" & " " & Right(exp, 2) & " "

        Case "V" & year
            monthYear = "OCT" & " " & Right(exp, 2) & " "

        Case "X" & year
            monthYear = "NOV" & " " & Right(exp, 2) & " "

        Case "Z" & year
            monthYear = "DEC" & " " & Right(exp, 2) & " "

    End Select

    'Call/Put designation
    If optionType = "CALL" Then

        GetMonthCode = monthYear & "Calls"

    ElseIf optionType = "PUT" Then

        GetMonthCode = monthYear & "Puts"

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I've never seen the `#If` in VBA, I had to [look it up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325486/if-else-end-if-what-do-the-hash-signs-mean-in-vba).

Comment: That's the first time I saw beginner code doing crazy pointer stuff in vba. Not sure the beginner tag is appropriate ... nice question

Comment: @Vogel612 I thought that for a bit. Then I tried to understand the code and concluded that beginner is definitely appropriate.

Comment: The code up top came from some help on Stackoverflow.  In fairness to me, i've done similar preprocessor commands in C++, but i am most definitely a beginner in VBA.  Any thoughts or opinions or recommendations is greatly appreciated.  Only way to get better is to have your Code out to be torn apart =) gently lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A wise programmer [once told me](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/101650/81541)

> What a fascinating solution! It seems that for every smart decision you made, you also threw in a poor decision or two.

This is how your code makes me feel. You clearly know a fair amount of technical details about implementing code that does stuff, but very little about implementing code that is **actually useful**. Code is only useful if you (and whoever else ever has to read/maintain/extend it) can easily understand what it is doing and why.

There's a lot here which I may get to later, but right now I'm going to focus on your naming, because it's really hard to understand your code when I have to stop every line to figure out what the hell each variable is trying to represent.

---

Names should be **Descriptive**, **Unambiguous** and **Concise**. In that order.

I should be able to read a variable name and instantly know what the variable represents, its' scope and a pretty good idea of its' data type.

`cmeDataBook` is a **good** variable name. It is a workbook, that contains the cme data. It is a workbook object, and its' in `camelCase` so its' scope is local to this procedure. And I can tell all that by reading it just once.

`oiProductCodesArrayCounter` is another **good** variable name. It's a counter (probably an index counter) for the `oiProductCodesArray`. Awesome.

This: `WshtNameCrnt` is **not** a good name. I **think** it's trying to say `currentWorksheetName` but I had to stop and think for a good 5-10 seconds. And I'm still not entirely sure that's right.  Screen real estate is cheap. Cognitive processing and understanding is **not**.

On that subject: I see `getBook` and I think "That's a method to get a workbook object? Maybe a boolean to denote whether a workbook should be retrieved?". Wait, what do you mean that's the **name** of the **active** workbook? Why on earth wouldn't you call it `activeWorkbookName`!

Continuing in the same vein: If something is a Worksheet object then that should be obvious from its' name. Rather than `data`, which could be meant to represent literally **anything** , how about `wsData`? just 2 characters makes it **so** much clearer what's going on here. `wsLo, wsWa, wsOh, wsAt`, the abbreviations are still painful to keep track of, but at least when they pop up in the code later, I'm going to know roughly what they are.

---

Your naming **conventions** are all over the place.

You should follow standard VBA naming conventions wherever possible. It allows other people to seamlessly absorb extra metaData about your code, and it allows you to do the same with the vast majority of professional VBA code.

Namely:

`camelCase` means a variable is local to a procedure.
`Dim localVariable`

`PascalCase` means a variable is global to a Module or the entire project.
`Private ModuleVariable, Public GlobalVariable`
It is also used for method names:
`Public Sub DoThisThing()`

`SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASE` is used for constants
`Public/Private Const CONSTANT_VALUE`

Method Names generally use `_` to denote event triggers. E.G.
`Private Sub Workbook_Open()`
So don't use them in your other Method Names.

*most* of your code follows these conventions, but there are enough variables that don't to render the whole thing worthless. Examples:

```
Public Const csURL As String
, OiProductCodesArray() As String
Dim ClearWshtsArray As Variant
Dim WshtNameCrnt As Variant
Private Function seperateData
```

---

Miscellaneous things that jump out at me:

---

```
Dim WshtNameCrnt As Variant
```

If this thing is always going to be used to hold text, then why not dim it as a string?

---

`Call` is deprecated. These 2 statements are functionaly identical:

```
Call seperateData(cmeDataBook, data, cvr, "cvr", 5)
seperateData cmeDataBook, data, cvr, "cvr", 5
```

---

`Integer` is also deprecated. The compiler will silently convert all `Integer`s to `Long`s, so just use `Long`.

---

Explicitly scope everything. This includes method arguments

```
Sub GetTotalVolumeData(volumeSheet As Worksheet, controlSheet As Worksheet)
```

Are those meant to be passed `ByRef` or `ByVal`?, because right now, they're *implicitly* being passed `ByRef`.

---

### Codenames

Codenames are big and clever. Every worksheet and workbook has a "name" that the user can see and change.

`Set data = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Data")`

is referencing a sheet name.

A Codename on the other hand is a secret name that can **only** be set/changed in the IDE.

[image]

the name in brackets is the "name". The name not in brackets is the "codename". It is set in the properties window.

[image]

If you give a sheet a codename (E.G. `wsData`) then the user can change the name as much as they like, all you have to do is use

`wsData.Name`

in your code and it will keep running.

It also means you can just delete this entire section of code:

```
getBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set cmeDataBook = Workbooks(getBook)
Set data = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Data")
Set controlPanel = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Control Panel")
Set lo = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Lo")
Set wa = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Wa")
Set sevenA = cmeDataBook.Sheets("7A")
Set oh = cmeDataBook.Sheets("oh")
Set at = cmeDataBook.Sheets("at")
Set ob = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Ob")
Set ra = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Ra")
Set cvr = cmeDataBook.Sheets("CVR")
Set ln = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Ln")
Set wtioi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("WtiOI")
Set rboboi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("RbobOI")
Set ethanoloi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("EthanolOI")
Set heatoi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("HeatOI")
Set sevenaoi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("7AOI")
Set waoi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("WAOI")
Set ngoi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("NGOI")
Set atoi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("ATOI")
Set raoi = cmeDataBook.Sheets("RAOI")
Set volumeSheet = cmeDataBook.Sheets("Total Volume By Product (CME)")
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations and thorough response I appreciate it!  I will implement those ideas more rigorously going forward.  I did not realize they were implicitly passed ByRef, but now that I think about it it makes perfect sense.  They should most likely be passed ByVal as in most of my subs there is no genuine need for the parameters themselves to be manipulated.

Comment: How would you recommend manipulating worksheets in excel without setting them using your method?  Would I just use the standard workbookOne.Sheets(wsData.Name) ?

Comment: @StormsEdge Once you give a sheet a codename, it is the equivalent of a global variable within that workbook. You can just reference it anywhere without having to declare it first.

Comment: That's fantastic.  Thank you for telling me that it was a pain declaring all those and a waste of time/space.  Thanks!

Comment: I just wanted to thank you again for writing that big response to my post.  I refer to it all the time during my projects and it has improved my code readability 10 fold.

Comment: @StormsEdge I'm really happy to hear that. You should keep throwing your code up here on CR, I guarantee we'll keep finding more ways to improve it ^^

Comment: absolutely.  I'm planning on posting a few more!  Definitely a big help.  I appreciate it.

Comment: That's a lot of useful things I didnt know either, and I wasnt specifically looking for that information but by no means have disappointment in being sidetracked by it. Seems I have a lot of VBA to refine :)